# catch or handle ProvisionedThroughputExceededException using Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I cannot seem to find an answer to this question.  My dynamodb table is loaded from a stream of items coming from an S3 bucket. I am using the aws sdk version 3  like so :

```
const ddbclient = new DynamoDBClient({region: process.env.REGION});

try{
const command = new BatchWriteItemCommand(params);
const response = await ddbclient.send(command);
}catch(e){
// handle error
}
```

This works well . But I keep getting a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException which is not caught by the catch block. I understood that if the batchWrite fails it would send unprocessed items back in the response of the await ddbclient.send(command) , which I can handle using code like

```
 if (hasUnprocessedItems(TABLE_NAME, response)) { // check there are unprocessed items
        setPause() // set an exponential backoff 
   
        putItemArray = response.UnprocessedItems[TABLE_NAME] // put the returned items back into a 
                                                            // collection to send again to dynamoDB
      }
```

But my code fails with a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException  and I do not seem to be able to catch this error or find solutions to  handle it.  Can someone tell me how to do this, I do not want to use on demand wrote capacity or increase my write capacity if at all  possible.

Alternatively can I check the DynamoDBClient instance for its current write capacity and if so how ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `const response = await ddbclient.send(command);` Assuming this is an sdk function as opposed to something you've written, aws sdk functions don't return promises, so awaiting it is pointless and therefore your catch block won't catch any exceptions. You need to await the result of the `promise` method on the the api call, e.g. `await client.function(params).promise();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the docs say const response = await client.send(command);. I'll try it though. Yes ddbclient.send(...).promise is not a function. I think version 3 is different here. But thanks for your time and comments

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realised there was a new (?) version of the sdk that returns promises!

Comment: If you have time could you tell me in version 2 can you just catch the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException in the catch block ?

Comment: In version 2 I would expect any exception resulting from the call to `send`, regardless of the exception type, to be caught by the `catch` block, so long as you are awaiting the call to `promise()`. I can't tell you about that specific error as I've never had to deal with it (nor do we use provisioned throughput) but I wouldn't expect the error type to matter - this isn't an aws thing, it's a javascript thing - the exception thrown by something awaited will be caught in the calling try/catch block.

Comment: If it's not, I would look into whether the exception is coming from somewhere else, or whether something is not being awaited properly (e.g. something is calling a method that returns a promise but that promise isn't being awaited, that will result in the exception not being caught by the catch block). Could even be a bug in the sdk but that would seem unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for all you advice. I appreciate it very much